# Custom notification for CalendarProvider events on Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, calendarcontract

I created a Calendar using the Calendar Provider for Android. I have got it all working fine and I even get the reminders working:

```
public static ContentValues getReminderContentValues(long eventId) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventId);
        cv.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        cv.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 15);
        return cv;
    }
```

With the above code, I am able to see the events in the default calendar application, Google Calendar and also my application.

I also get a notification 15 minutes before the scheduled start. Now I want to customize the notification in a sense that when I click on the notification, it would go to my app instead of the default calendar application or Google calendar.

I have tried to register a broadcast with the [ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER) in the manifest like:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.ReminderReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

With this, I am able to get the code in the `onReceive` method of the broadcast receiver but if I write a notification there too, then I will have 2 notifications being displayed. One which works fine while the other which takes me to default application upon click.

Any solution as to how could I get the reminder notification to open my app or to block the default reminder notification and create a new one altogether?

An alternate solution would be schedule an alarm with the help of `AlarmManager` on the exact time of the event, but since there will be many such intents, they will basically override each other! Any solution to this?